# How do we stream a data pipeline for data transfer from snowflake to kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task, snowflake-pipe

I want to get the transformed data from snowflake to my postgres database. To achieve this I want to move the data from snowflake to kafka and then from kafka to postgres. Not able to figure out how to move data from snowflake to kafka.

Comment: I understand the following: You want to unload data from Snowflake to  AWS/Azure/GCP and from there Kafka has to consume it? Right?

Answer (score 0):

- You can use NiFi to get data from Snowflake and send it to a kafka
  topic
- you can use a three party like Fivetran
- You can use copy into to S3 or cloud storage and use a listener to get the new events https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-s3.html